# Module `Ledger.Typed.Scripts' does not export `wrapValidator'

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

I try to compile code from [Plutus Pioneer Program week 4](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/6be7484d4b8cffaef4faae30588c7fb826bcf5a3/code/week04/src/Week04/Vesting.hs#L64). These lines cause error.

```
typedValidator :: Scripts.TypedValidator Vesting
typedValidator = Scripts.mkTypedValidator @Vesting
    $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| mkValidator ||])
    $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| wrap ||])
  where
    wrap = Scripts.wrapValidator @VestingDatum @()
```

Here is the error:

```
Not in scope: `Scripts.wrapValidator'
Perhaps you meant one of these:
`Scripts.tvValidator' (imported from Ledger.Typed.Scripts),
data constructor `Scripts.TypedValidator' (imported from Ledger.Typed.Scripts)
Module `Ledger.Typed.Scripts' does not export `wrapValidator'.
```

That is strange because from the [documentation](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger/html/Ledger-Typed-Scripts.html#t:Any) there is the instance `wrapValidator` in `Ledger.Typed.Scripts`

> wrapValidator :: forall d r. (UnsafeFromData d, UnsafeFromData r) => (d -> r -> ScriptContext -> Bool) -> WrappedValidatorType

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the week04 code is unchanged, ensure you have run checked out commit [ea1bfc](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/6be7484d4b8cffaef4faae30588c7fb826bcf5a3/code/week04/cabal.project#L45) in the `plutus-apps` repo and run `nix-shell` within plutus-apps. Then switch to the week 4 directory in the nix shell and `cabal build` should work.